# case class filter criteria in Slick 3.0.3

Tags: scala, design-patterns, repository-pattern, slick, slick-3.0

I have a Model, corresponding Table and a Repository. In my repository, using TableQuery I want to find a model object based on some criteria (a function from model to boolean), which the repository have no control, it is injected as a parameter. E.g.

```
case class JournalEntryModel(id: Option[Long] = None, isDebit: Boolean, principal: Double)

class JournalEntryTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[JournalEntryModel](tag, "journal_entries") {

   def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

   def isDebit = column[Boolean]("is_debit")  

   def principal = column[Double]("principal")

   def * = (id.?, isDebit, principal) <>
      (JournalEntryModel.tupled, JournalEntryModel.unapply)
}

object journalEntries extends TableQuery(new JournalEntryTable(_))

object Repository {

    def find(criteria: JournalEntryModel => Boolean): List[JournalEntryModel] = db.run {
         journalEntries.filter(je => criteria(je)).result            
    } toList
}

val credits = Repository.find(!_.isDebit && _.principal > 500.0)
```

How do I write a such a filter function ?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about why the solution you have in your question doesn't work. Does it not compile or does it simply not return the correct results?

Answer (score -1):

I think your question is "How do I write a function literal for `JournalEntryModel => Boolean`"?

If you want to do it with a literal like you have, you need to define your parameters:

```
// Parameter list ("model" here) is required. You also need the argument type(s).
// Here, they're inferred from the argument to "find".
val credits = Repository.find(model => !model.isDebit && model.principal > 500.0)
```